# Why does the Gaussian function has an additional factor of 1/2 in the exponent?

Tags: definition, normal-distribution, exponentiation, gaussian-integral, gaussian

What is the reason behind the seemingly arbitrary factor of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{{2}}$ in the exponent of the [Gaussian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_function)?

Sometimes, as in this Wikipedia article on the [Gaussian integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral), the factor $\displaystyle\frac{1}{{2}}$ is omitted and it's not obvious why one should include it at all. It's just another factor one has to take care of (i.e. a possible source of error when doing calculations by hand).

As far as I can tell, it just scales the width parameter (e.g. the [standard deviation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation) $\displaystyle\sigma$ or the [full width at half-maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full_width_at_half_maximum)) by a "strange" factor of $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{2}}}$ and seems to serve no real purpose.

Comment: It appears naturally if you want to write the pdf of the normal distribution in terms of the standard deviation $\sigma$: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution . Perhaps it would help psychologically to think of $- \frac{1}{2} x^2$ as the integral of $-x$. Similar factors of $\frac{1}{2}$ show in e.g. the definition of kinetic energy in physics.

Comment: Ultimately this is a convention though. You can see the difference between the two conventions in this discussion of the probabilists' vs. the physicists' Hermite polynomials: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Definition

Comment: Hi, could you briefly elaborate on the idea of explaining the factor with the integration of $\displaystyle-{x}$? Also, how is it *natural* to appear when using the standard deviation and how does it connect to the integral of $\displaystyle-{x}$? I understand that the general Gaussian integral is finite and normalized to 1 in the case of the normal distribution, which explains the normalization constants

Comment: ...differently put: Why don't we just absorb $\displaystyle\frac{1}{{2}}$ into $\displaystyle\sigma$?

Comment: You mean into the standard deviation? I mean, you could, but then you'd introduce a factor of $2$ into the statement of theorems like Chebyshev's inequality: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality

Comment: @QiaochuYuan: Sorry, I meant: Why not absorb $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{2}}}$ into $\displaystyle\sigma$ (in the exponent of the normal distribution)

Comment: I.e. what part in the definition of $\displaystyle\sigma$ motivates its definition such that in the normal distribution the width parameter needs to be scaled by another factor of  $\displaystyle\sqrt{{{2}}}$? Why does it make sense to define $\displaystyle\sigma$ by a factor of $\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{{{2}}}}$ "***smaller** than "necessary"*? Because I suspect there is *some* reason behind this (one which is not obvious for me)

Answer (score 1):

One of the reasons to add the $\frac{1}{2}$ factor could be that the inflexion point is then nicely related with $\sigma$, otherwise you would have the $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ factor between the inflexion point and $\sigma$

[You can clearly see this on this graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GH7Q.png)